# Can I convert p8 APNs Auth Key to pem file?

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications, pem

I using `*.p8` APNs Auth Keys instead of `*.p12` certificates for push notification of my apps.

And, push notifications were working well.

However, a third party SDK which I needed and related to push notification demands only `*.pem` files from me, not `*.p8`.

If I want to use only `*.p8` for APNs, I can't use this SDK now. It's right?

Comment: Did you figure out if this is possible?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do this by using `openssl`. You can convert the .p8 to .pem using below command:

If the .p8 private key is encrypted:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in AuthKey.p8 -out AuthKey.pem
```

If the .p8 private key is not encrypted:

```
openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in AuthKey.p8 -out AuthKey.pem
```

APNS and Sign in with Apple *.p8 keys, provided by Apple are unencrypted.

Comment: I needed `-nocrypt` for my Auth0 Sign In With Apple Bridge

Comment: Creates an empty file for me.